# What is the result of the macro?

Tags: c

Could anyone tell me what is the result of the following macro with explanation. id is 32 bit

```
#define ARBITR(id) ((unsigned long)(id) >> 21 & 0x000000ff | \
                    (unsigned long)(id) >>  5 & 0x0000ff00 | \
                    (unsigned long)(id) << 11 & 0x00ff0000 | \
                    (unsigned long)(id) << 27)
```

Comment: gcc -E will expand macros for you

Comment: @Mike: I suspect the questioner also wants to know what the expression resulting from the macro expansion actually does (and, perhaps, what significance or purpose it might have).

Comment: of course, i was just offering a tip. that's why i didn't put it into a full answer

Answer (score 4):

It shuffles the bits of `id` as follows:

- bits 27-31 contain the original bits 0-4
- bits 16-23 contain the original bits 5-12
- bits 8-15 contain the original bits 13-20
- bits 0-7 contain the original bits 21-28

To know the purpose of this you'd have to look at larger purpose of the code.

Comment: My guess is it's a hashing macro.